# How to exit from from game loop without closing the application?

Tags: c#, xna

How I create and run the instance of the game:

```cs
 using (Game1 game = new Game1())
 {
       game.Run();
       MessageBox.Show("Game finished");
       // A lot of other things that I don't want to do inside the game" 
 }
```

If inside the game, at a certain point, I write:

```
this.Exit();
```

The Application closes entirely, and the MessageBox is never shown.

How can I just let `.Run()` return?

Edit: I noticed that clicking onto the "x" of the window while the game is running gives the effect I want

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting.aspx might help, something like this should do your thing (put that in your `Game` class):

```
protected override void OnExiting (Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Game finished");
}
```

Comment: I tried the same, the problem is that I don't have access to the Run() method, because it is from the Game class of XNA library... I can only write something into the Update() and Draw() methods

Comment: Thanks, but MessageBox.Show("Game finished"); was just a placeholder for "a lot of other things that I don't want to do inside the game"

Comment: Well, nothing stops you to do so, if your things to do are visible/accessible from the `Game` class or e.g. members of an extended `Game` class created by you (`Object sender` is your `Game` class object).

Comment: _"but MessageBox.Show("Game finished"); was just a placeholder for 'a lot of other things that I don't want to do inside the game'"_ - you want to avoid potentially changing the rules in a **comment** after someone posts an answer based on the current info in your original question